# Recommended way to one-hot encode in keras: text preprocessing layers

Tags: keras, nlp, artificial-intelligence, data-preprocessing

I'm trying to use keras to create a text preprocessing pipeline and I'm wanting to one-hot encode my sentences at the character level. I'm using a `TextVectorization` layer to convert my sentences to integers and then trying to use something like a `CategoryEncoding` to convert the integers to one-hot representations. It doesn't seem like `CategoryEncoding` is really set up to do this though because it only lets me output tensors of rank 2 (and in this case the tensors would be of rank 3: `(num sentences, max sentence len, num characters)`.

I can obviously roll my own solution here and preprocess the text manually, but I've been reading that it's a best practice to have the preprocessing baked into the model itself. This also seems like it would be a really common use case and rolling my own solution feels hack-ey. All the examples I see online are made in pure python like this and I've yet to see one that uses high-level keras layers. Is there a best practice on how to do something like this? Is the best solution really manually preprocessing the text and there's no keras built-in?

Pseudo-code for what I'm trying to do. This will fail at the CategoryEncoding step though:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sentences = [
  'my name is David',
  'what is your name',
]
sentences_arr = np.array(sentences)

tv = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
  output_mode='int',
  split='character',
)
tv.adapt(sentences)

unique_chars = tv.get_vocabulary()
num_unique_chars = len(unique_chars)
ce = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=num_unique_chars, output_mode='one_hot')

print('TextVectorization:')
vectorized_sentences = tv(sentences_arr)
print(vectorized_sentences, end='\n\n')

print('CategoryEncoding:')
cat_encoded_sentences = ce(vectorized_sentences)
print(cat_encoded_sentences)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider implementing a lambda function instead of `CategoryEncoding`for one-hot encoding

```
one_hot_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.one_hot(x, num_unique_chars))
```

The Lambda layer outputs a tensor of shape (num sentences, max sentence len, num characters), which corresponds to the one-hot encoded sentences.

Output:

```
TextVectorization:
tf.Tensor(
[[ 4  6  2  8  3  4  9  2  5  7  2 10  3 12  5 10  0]
 [11 17  3 14  2  5  7  2  6 16 13 15  2  8  3  4  9]], shape=(2, 17), dtype=int64)

One-Hot Encoded Sentences:
tf.Tensor(
[[[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]], shape=(2, 17, 18), dtype=float32)
```

Custom padding-sequence

```
# Custom Lambda function for one-hot encoding with padding correction
def one_hot_padding_correction(x):
    # Replacing the padded character index (0) with -1
    x = tf.where(tf.equal(x, 0), -1, x)
    return tf.one_hot(x, num_unique_chars)

# Lambda layer using the custom function for one-hot encoding
one_hot_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(one_hot_padding_correction)
```

Comment: Excellent! This is very close to what I want--very elegant. One question:

The first sentence provided "my name is David" has 16 characters whereas the 2nd sentence "what is your name" has 17. The first sentence therefore has to be 'padded' by an additional character.

The 1-hot encoding above represents the padded character as [1, 0, 0, ...] though I think it would be more accurate to represent it as [0, 0, 0, ...] right? Because it denotes the absence of a character in that position? 1) Is that thinking correct and (2) if it is how do I get that behavior?

Comment: Visual of what I mean: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LTOFqqgm_rFx-JOt_1Xg2Xm_XvIXb28_/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: This is the default implementation of one-hot encoder. You can customize it by replacing  index(0) by -1 temporarily. I'll edit the answer